# Find where $y=a^x$ intersects $y=\log_a (x)$.

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

I have found the following surprisingly nice result.

> The graph of $y=a^x$ intersects its inverse $y=\log_a(x)$ when $a=e^{\frac{1}{e}}$ at $x=e$.

**Question:** Is there a faster way of proving this result than below? The method below feels too long.

**My method:**
Let the intersection point be at $x=X$.

The two curves must intersect on the line $y=x$. $$a^X=X$$

The line $y=x$ is a tangent.

$$a^X \ln (a) = 1$$

Combine results.

$$X =\frac{1}{\ln (a)} \,\,\,\,\,\,\,(*)$$

But also

$$\log_a(X)=X=\frac{\ln(X)}{\ln(Aa)}$$

Substitute in $(*)$

$$\frac{1}{\ln(a)}=\frac{\ln(X)}{\ln(a)}$$

Hence $x=e$. $$a^e=e$$ 
Therefore $$a=e^{\frac{1}{e}} \,\,\,\,\,\, \square$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two graphs are *inverses*, thus their intersection points all happen when either graph passes through $y=x$.

Hence you are looking to solve:
$$a^x=x$$
or$$\log_a(x)=x$$This is at $a=x^\frac1x$ or $a=\sqrt[x]{x}$ (same thing but second one is more obvious).